# Passing an animation function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am trying to pass a fadeIn/fadeOut/etc function as a parameter to a larger function, but it's not working. This is how I initiate it:

```
$("#buttFadeOut").click(function() {
    $('#lista').fade( function () {
        fadeOut(500);
    }, 150);
});
```

And this is where it goes:

```
$.fn.fade = function(passedFunction, pauseDuration){
var elem = this.children().first();
var len = elem.siblings().length;
for (var i=0;i<=len;i++) {
    var fun = passedFunction();
        elem.delay(pauseDuration*i).passedFunction();
    }
    elem = elem.next();
}
```

I get the error saying that elem.delay(...).passedFunction is not a function, but if I check it with $.isFunction(passedFunction) it returns true. With normal functions it's working but (if I'm assuming correctly) since I'm running it on 'elem' it refuses to work. Any fixes for that?

Comment: You are right. `elem.delay().passedFunction()` will be `undefined` as it is passed in as a parameter, not a method of an element. - Use it like a standalone function.

Comment: So what exactly am I supposed to do in this situation? I can't use switch/case in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem.delay(pauseDuration*i).passedFunction();` tries to call a jQuery plugin called `passedFunction()` which is not there.

One solution could be to pass a callback function like below, you might also have to move `elem = elem.next();` inside the `for` loop

```js
$("#buttFadeOut").click(function() {
  $('#lista').fade(function(el) {
    $(el).fadeOut(500);
  }, 250);
});


$.fn.fade = function(passedFunction, pauseDuration) {
  var elem = this.children().first();
  var len = elem.siblings().length;
  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    elem.delay(pauseDuration * i).promise().done(function() {
      passedFunction(this);
    });
    elem = elem.next();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttFadeOut">Test</button>
<ul id="lista">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`passedFunction()` is a reference to an anonymous function. You cannot call it from the jQuery object resulting from the `delay()` call. You need to call it separately:

```
$.fn.fade = function(passedFunction, pauseDuration) {
    var elem = this.children().first();
    var len = elem.siblings().length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        elem.delay(pauseDuration * i);
        passedFunction();
    }
    elem = elem.next();
}
```

Assuming that both animations are set to operate on the same queue (which they will be by default) then this should work fine.